# QThread::getCurrentThread() from non-Qt thread

Tags: multithreading, qt

What will I get from `QThread::getCurrentThread()`, if it is called from `non-Qt thread`?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: Do you mean QThread::currentThread()? And another question: why would you do that?

Comment: It's undefined behavior probably.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`QThread` is just a wrapper, behind the scene it uses native threads.

`QThread::currentThread` creates and initialises a `Q(Adopted)Thread` instance if it doesn't exist yet.

In case of unix it uses `pthread`s.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <pthread.h>

#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>

void run() {
    QThread *thread = QThread::currentThread();

    qDebug() << thread;
    std::cout << QThread::currentThreadId() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    std::cout << pthread_self() << std::endl;

    thread->sleep(1);
    std::cout << "finished\n";
}

int main() {
    std::thread t1(run);
    t1.join();
}
```

Output:

```
QThread(0x7fce51410fd0) 
0x10edb6000
0x10edb6000
0x10edb6000
finished
```

I see that [there](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/blobs/stable/src/corelib/thread/qthread_unix.cpp#line229) is initialisation of Qt application main thread:

```
data->threadId = (Qt::HANDLE)pthread_self();
if (!QCoreApplicationPrivate::theMainThread)
    QCoreApplicationPrivate::theMainThread = data->thread;
```

So there might be some side effects.

I'd advise not to mix QThread with non-Qt threads.

Comment: What side effects might there be? Why don't you advise to mix them?

Comment: Is the other way around compatible? i.e. create a thread using `QThread`s and then get id using `this_thread::get_id()`.