# Using Qt signals/slots with non-Qt threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I've done my due diligence but can't find an answer to this one:

How does the Qt signal/slot mechanism interact with non-Qt threads?

In particular, is it safe to emit a signal from a non-Qt (e.g. [TBB](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/)) thread, to be caught by a slot in my main event loop?  Supposing I connect it with a queued connection explicitly?  (My feeling is that specifying that the connection is queued would be mandatory; is this correct?)

(As a side question, I have been assuming that in general, the Qt synchronization classes, e.g. `QMutex`, work across non-Qt threads.  Is this correct?)

(As a clarifying remark, the thing that I'm worried about is that the queued connection mechanism will not use guards, e.g. mutexes, to add the metacall to the main thread event queue if it does not detect that the signal is being emitted from a different Qt thread.)

(Final addition: I can believe that because the Qt mechanisms are implemented in terms of platform-specific primitives, that in practice all of the things that I am trying to do will just work gracefully, but I'm also wondering if Qt provides any guarantees that these things will work.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads.html) states:

> **Note:** Qt's threading classes are implemented with native threading APIs; e.g., Win32 and pthreads. Therefore, they can be used with threads of the same native API.

So yes, Qt's mutexes will work with other threads (as long as they also use the same native API).

The difference between Qt threads and other threads is that other threads will never have Qt's event loop running, so won't be able to receive and handle any signals. However, if you'll run the event loop ([`exec`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#exec)) inside such a thread everything should work fine.

The signal related functions, mainly [`processEvents`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) and [`postEvent`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#postEvent) are said to be thread safe:

> **Note:** This function is thread-safe.

If the objects have the thread affinity set correctly (using the [`moveToThread`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#moveToThread) method) you don't need to set the connection type explicitly, the default [`AutoConnection`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) works as follows:

> (default) If the signal is emitted in the thread which the receiving object has affinity then the behavior is the same as the Direct Connection. Otherwise, the behavior is the same as the Queued Connection.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16210064/2642204) suggests that non-Qt threads should also be correctly identifiable by Qt's methods - [`currentThread`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#currentThread) should return a `QThread` instance even for a non-Qt thread, as it's only a wrapper over native threads.